# install previous hwe kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualization

Can someone give some hints how to solve the problem
the essence:

Ubuntu 18.04. LTS guest VM machine.
initially boot gives an error `Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e` but boots, and in HYPER-V status of SR-IOV is OK.

When kernel is updated to `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`
the error disappears. However the status of SR-IOV is not operational (degraded).

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.3.0.53.110
  Version table:
     5.3.0.53.110 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
```

How do I install the package with previous version of the kernel?

Where would I look for all versions if there is only one available in repository?

In 16.04LTS, SR-IOV works with HWE.

Comment: You can't install a previous hwe kernel, you can switch to non-hwe kernel, the 4.15.

Comment: but you can donwload previous version and install ubuntu with hwe
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.3/

Comment: After the first upgrade the new kernel will be installed again. The old one won't get security updates, etc.

Comment: sudo apt-mark hold linux-generic-hwe-18.04

Comment: That won't work. You need to hold a couple of other packages too. And it is really a bad idea to use an unsupported kernel.